# Informed badge on meta

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

When I open my profile on meta, my next (and recommended) badge is the `Informed` badge.

1. Why does this badge exists here even though I earned it in SO ? I know badges here are different, but the question is more like if people read the tour on SO, they should already know it and have the badge also here.
2. When I clicked on "Go get it" to take the tour and earn the badge here, it redirect me from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tour to https://stackoverflow.com/tour and this badge is not earned.

EDIT:

This badge doesn't exist in the list of badge but it exist in my profile

[image: My Meta Profile]

Is this a bug?

Comment: Some badges are simply not earnable. StackExchange has an (inconsistent) policy that options should be shown even if they are not yet/entirely not possible.

Comment: The Informed Badge *doesn't* exist on meta. It not on the [list of badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges) for the site. I guess the devs of the next badge feature just didn't think it worthwhile to account for differences on meta.

Comment: Yeah ! You're right it doesn't exist in the list. Check my edit for a screenshot of my profile on meta. Is this a bug?

Comment: Already reported on the master bug list: [New profile pages are out - bugs and feedback master list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253486)

Comment: What's weird is that it isn't in the list but if you "Go get it" it will show up as one you earned afterward. It just disappears later.

Comment: Oh great ! I just checked that link.. Thanks @MartijnPieters for pointing me to that page !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This bug has been [resolved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253486).

Comment: This bug has not completely been resolved. As a new user, you see the text (and link) "Take the Tour and earn your first badge" on multiple meta pages (in my case they are meta.unix.stackexchange.com and meta.superuser.com)

Comment: @DanielAlder: I tested and just earned the badge on [meta.se]. Also, you don't seem to have earned it for either that or [su]. Try it.

Comment: Meta Stack Exchange is different to the other meta pages, because it's not a real meta page. The rest of your comment is unclear for me what you want to say

Comment: @DanielAlder: Follow the instructions to earn the badge, and if you have it on main, but main or meta still prompt, consider opening a new bug on the respective meta referencing the earlier one. I think it would be a regression.